# dockerでport forwardingがうまくいかない

Tags: ubuntu, docker, flask

`docker run -it -p 8080:8080 ubuntu:20.04`を実行した後
コンテナ内で

```
apt update
apt install python3 python3-pip curl nano
pip install flask
```

で環境構築した後に

```py
# test.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)
```

`python3 test.py`を実行しています。

コンテナ内で
`curl localhost:8080`や`curl 172.17.0.2:8080`を実行すると"hello"と正常に動作するのですが、
**ホストpcから`curl localhost:8080`や`curl 172.17.0.2:8080`を実行しても

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`と正常に動作しません。**

どのようにすればホストからアクセスできるようになるでしょうか？

以下の環境でdockerを利用しています。

- ubuntu21.04
- Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

---

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND   CREATED       STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
f370c9214bf8   ubuntu:20.04   "bash"    2 hours ago   Up 6 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   jovial_elgamal

$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-09-12 19:26:33 JST; 6 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 3205 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 37
     Memory: 146.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             ├─   3205 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
             ├─3029807 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 8080
             └─3029813 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 8080
```

---

ちなみにdockerの環境は以下のようにして構築しました

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Comment: 手元の環境は `ubuntu 21.04`, `Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu1~21.04.1` ですが、ホストからアクセスできています(`hello`が表示されます)。`docker ps` と `systemctl status docker` の実行結果を教えてもらえますか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。上記の通りの実行結果になります

Comment: 考えられる状況として、ホスト側でプロキシサーバを利用しているという事はありませんか？ `curl --noproxy localhost localhost:8080` を試してみて下さい。

Comment: プロキシサーバは利用していないですが、念のため実行してみましたが、`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`となり、特に変化なしです。
同じhost pc(ubuntu20.10)にvmwareも入っているのですが、これが悪さをしているという可能性はありますか？